# Samsung galaxy S6 is secretly recording my phone calls and the environment around me

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

Verizon is my service provider. I have a folder on my phone called VZMedia under device storage. Within this folder are more than 10 recordings. The file format of these recordings are .amr. These recordings come in two types. first, some of these recordings are phones calls I have recently made. Second, some of these recordings are of noise around me. for example in some of the recordings I can hear conversations I've had with friends or a TV program I have on while I am at my apartment. the folder continues to be populated with new records every couple weeks. I reached out to Verizon and they said that folder and what it is doing is not associated with them. My guess is one of the apps I have maybe be the cause of this. But this seems like a serious breach of my privacy. I Google search has yielded no help with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is funny, because they have an article about it, related to the S6
http://www.verizonwireless.com/mobile-living/tech-smarts/how-to-record-audio-smartphone/

The phone apparently has a pre-installed app for audio recording which may be malfunctioning

Answer (score 1):

Found several messages about this.  I believe it has nothing to do with the voice recorder, as it uses a different format than AMR.

The one consistency i've seen with people experiencing this problem is that they're all using the 'Message+' app for text messaging.  It's got a microphone icon next to the input box and it's possible to accidentally activate it.

Go to settings
Applications
App manager
Message+
then 
Permissions

You should see on/off switches for microphone, camera, etc.

Turn the Microphone and location switches to 'OFF'

This should eliminate the problem.